# Why Bullet chart shows decimal number when we have range 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm using nvd3-bullet-chart from angularjs-nvd3-directives library to display maximum, current data. It will work If I have a minimum number greater than 2. It shows whole number.But if I have maximum number = 1, then it shows decimal number.
How Can I remove decimal numbers? Any help Would be appreciated, thanks.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'bulletChart',
      transitionDuration: 500,
      height: 70,
      margin: {
        top: 10,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 125
      }
    },
    title: {
      enable: true,
      text: 'Title for Line Chart',
      css: {
        'text-align': 'center',
        'font-size': '12px'
      }
    }



  };



  $scope.dataset = {

    data: {
      "title": "Revenue",
      "subtitle": "US$, in thousands",
      "ranges": [1],
      "measures": [0],
      "markers": [0]
    },
    data2: {
      "title": "Revenue",
      "subtitle": "US$, in thousands",
      "ranges": [150, 225, 300],
      "measures": [220],
      "markers": [250]
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.4/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>

<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="data in dataset">
    <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
  </div>


  <br><a href="http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/" target="_blank" style="float: right;">See more</a>
</body>
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/C5LE0qr3QdElZ8Uuenyy?p=preview). you can see row 1.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you desire...

Comment: bullet number 1 is showing decimals number in his axis 0.0 , 0.1

Comment: you can use tickFormat to format those values

Comment: I did but its not working on bullet chart

Comment: Also checked my example below?

Comment: Actually We dont need a percentage .

Comment: It's only an example... Check this site for other formatting rules: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `tickFormat`?

Here is a snippet exemplifying % formatting of tick values:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'bulletChart',
      transitionDuration: 500,
      height: 70,
      margin: {
        top: 10,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 125
      },
      tickFormat: function(d) {
          return d3.format('%')(d);
      },
    },
    title: {
      enable: true,
      text: 'My Chart',
      css: {
        'text-align': 'center',
        'font-size': '14px'
      }
    }

  };

  $scope.data = {
      "title": "Revenue",
      "subtitle": "%",
      "ranges": [0, 1],
      "measures": [0.1],
      "markers": [0.5],
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular-nvD3 Bullet Chart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.2/nv.d3.min.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.16/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.2/nv.d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.5/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  
      <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>

  </body>

</html>
```